# Download file in javascript is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is the code

```
function ExportToExcel() {
            if ($("#dateRange").val() != "") {
                var frm = $("#frmProjectReport").serialize();
                var url = "/Reports/ProjectExcelReport?" + frm;
                Download(url);

            }
        }

        function Download(url) {
            alert(url);
            //var win = window.open(url, "DownloadWin", "resizable=0,status=0,toolbar=0,width=600px,height=300px");
            var win = window.open(url, "DownloadWin", "width=600px,height=300px,scrollbars=yes ,menubar=no,location=no,left=0,top=0")
            win.focus();
            win.moveTo(100, 100);
        }
```

its working in all browser except chrome.

I have used frame also as below code but it does't work in case of huge data..

```
 function Download(url) {
            try {
                $("#fileIframe").html("");
                var iframe = $('<iframe name="postframe" id="postframe" class="hidden" frameBorder="0" src="about:none" />');
                $('#fileIframe').append(iframe);
                $('#frmProjectReport').attr("action", url);
                $('#frmProjectReport').attr("method", "post")
                $('#frmProjectReport').attr("target", "postframe")
                $('#frmProjectReport').submit();

                //win = window.open(url, "DownloadWin", "width=600px,height=300px,scrollbars=yes ,menubar=no,location=no,left=0,top=0")
                //win.focus();
                //win.moveTo(100, 100);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e)
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you checked your popup blocker?

Comment: What is happening in chrome? If window is not opening then it may be because of pop-up blocker.

Comment: ya i did... code working in all browser except chorme.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way we export an excel file using an `IFRAME`:

```
function download(src){
    var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(ifr);
    ifr.src = src;
    ifr.onload = function(e){
        document.body.removeChild(ifr);
        ifr = null;
    };
}
```

It works in all browsers, and has the advantage of not popping up a window.

Comment: Thanks Mic for your response.but this also caused problem when the data is very large in serialize object.At that situation nothing is happen.In my case data is in very huge amount.

Comment: The amount of data you send with a GET request(in the url) is limited and depends on the browser. If it is huge, you need to first call your backend with a POST, receive an id and then make the GET call with this id.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function Download(url){
    try
    {
        var win = window.open(url,"DownloadWin","width=600px,height=300px,scrollbars=yes ,menubar=no,location=no,left=0,top=0");
        try
        {
            win.focus();
            win.moveTo(100, 100);
        }catch(e){/*Focus|moveTo not supported*/}
    }catch(e){/*open not supported, doubt it.*/}
}
```

I think it may be down to the moveTo() method as Chrome is a pure tabbed browser.

Also try check out the `window.resizeTo(100,100)`

Comment: i had tried this also robert,but it did't work for me.Thanks for response.