# jQuery / javascript download file doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery script in which I want to download a file which is located on some server after the user clicks on the link. On IE11 this works alright, as I simply make a call to:

```
window.open('file:///MyServer0001/SomeFolder/Tmp/ToiletFlush.log'
```

I know that for security reasons, Chrome doesn't allow to use the protocol file:/// . It is interesting because if I write myself this URL on the address bar he will show the file, however if I make a call for window.open() he just opens me a new empty window. Also, removing the file:/// , doesn't do anything on Chrome, it says that the page is not available

So right now I don't know how to make this work on chromium. I thought I could make a workaround by calling the controller function through a POST/GET , return a FileResult and download the file. This definitely works but I would like to  know a simple way to do this directly only using jQuery/JavaScript.

Any Idea?

Comment: Have you thought about using an IFRAME for this? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3758048/3509874

Comment: @urbz yes mate, I've seen this answer before, I tried it but it doesn't produce any result neither on IE nor Chrome. Nothing happens.. and the code snippet looks weird as well... I guess I will have to workaround by returning a FileResult from the controller..... This is extremely sad

Answer (score 2):

Try ASP.NET MVC FileResult:

View:

```
<a href='@Url.Action('GetFile','Home')">Download File</a>
```

In Home Controller:

```
public FileResult GetFile()
{
//Read file content into variable.
string content=File.ReadAllText("filepath");
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
return File(byteArray, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, "ToiletFlush.log");
}
```

Comment: I clearly wrote on my question that I can do this workaround. But if it is possible I would like to achieve this without calling any function from the controller and do everything strictly on jQuery / JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

On Windows:
1. Find the local URL of your Chrome Install
2. From the Command Line launch Chrome w/ '–allow-file-access-from-files' prepended to it:

```
–allow-file-access-from-files C://...
```

On OSX, just type this in Terminal:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files

Using Google Chrome Canary is also possible:

open /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Or... You'll need to run your application on a local server.

Comment: Not a valid option. The application is running on a server and it is being used by dozens of users. I cannot ask all of them to change Chrome settings as you may imagine ;)